# Datepicker- Week starts on Sunday with Week number

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

How do I display week starts from Sunday in datepicker along with week numbers.

eg: I need Week starting from 12/03/23(Sunday) should display week number 11 instead of 10. Any help appreciated. thanks

[image]

my code:-

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.date-picker').datepicker({
    showWeek: true,
    firstDay: 0,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: false,
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    autoclose: true,
  });
});
```

```html
<input name="sel-date" id="sel-date" class="date-picker" value="<?= $week_start ?>">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `calculateWeek` property from the datepicker also you can use `beforeShowDay` to disable the dates like i have done in the snippet..

let me know

Date Picker on input field:

```js
$(function(){
 $('.date-picker').datepicker({   
   showWeek: true,      
   firstDay: 0,
   changeMonth: true,
   changeYear: true,
   showButtonPanel: false,
   dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
   autoclose: true,
   calculateWeek: date => $.datepicker.iso8601Week(new Date(date)) + 1,
   beforeShowDay: function(date) {
     return [date.getDay() === 0,''];
   },  
 });
});
```

```css
#ui-datepicker-div { font-size: 12px; }
```

```html
Date Picker on input field: <input name="sel-date" id="sel-date" class="date-picker" value="12/03/2023">


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`calculateWeek`](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-calculateWeek) function to change the week number:

```js
$('.date-picker').datepicker({
  showWeek: true,
  firstDay: 0,
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  showButtonPanel: false,
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
  autoclose: true,
  calculateWeek: date => $.datepicker.iso8601Week(new Date(date)) + 1,
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
Date Picker on input field: <input type="text" name="sel-date" id="sel-date" class="date-picker">
```